# App running on iPad while its iPhone-Only

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, app-store-connect

I made an iPhone App with Xcode. The devices setting is set to "iPhone". But in iTunes Connect it is rejected because it doesn't run on the iPad.

That is weird because it is an iPhone app, but when I checked it in Xcode, I can run it with the iPad simulator,however I think that normally this is not possible with an iPhone app.

I have added pictures to make my question clearer:
[image: Devices set to iPhone-only]

[image: It's still giving the possibility to run on iPad simulator..]

So what is gone wrong and how can I fix it?

EDIT:
Picture from resolution center:
[image]

Comment: 'All' iPhone apps run on the iPad, they just don't use the full screen

Comment: when u create your project did u choose Universal app ? because if u did and u just change it after that like in your image to iPhone this maybe the problem

Comment: I don't remember, but how can I fix it?

Answer (score 8):

Thanks all, I Found the problem/solution:

In my info.plist there was an extra row called supported interface orientations(iPad) where the portrait mode was added.

I have no idea how this got added here but when I removed it, the problem was solved.

Comment: I did that and it still does not work.  Was there anything else you did?  I got the same rejection from App Review.

Answer (score 4):

From the Apple iOS App Store Review Guidelines (https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

**2.10 iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution**

Basically, if you set an app to "Universal" it will have iPad and iPhone versions of the UI and will appear in the search results for both. If you set it to iPhone only, it will still be installable on iPads, but it doesn't appear in the search results by default. Additionally when a user does install it on an iPad it will just scale up the UI to best fit the screen. You cannot prevent your app from running on iPads.

Comment: Ok I get that, but how will a game made for iPhones not be able to show up well on an iPad, since it is sort of a shown in iPhone mode.. I even have a special version for the iPad, I have released several apps and I have never got this before..

Comment: Your special version for the iPad will be the one that shows up by default for users in the search, but they can choose to install the iPhone version instead. You'll need to test the iPhone version on the iPad simulator, to make sure it runs. By default the iPad will run it at iPhone resolution, so it will look a bit blurry but it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

Every app can run on the iPad no matter if it is supported or not. The option you have in Xcode is if you want to configure it to look good on the iPad using it's own storyboard. If you configure it for both iPad and iPhone your app fill get a **+** in the right corner of the price on the App Store and show up on iPad searches. However if you don't configure it to support iPads it'll not show up on searches of the Apple App Store, unless osmose selects iPhone only. You can easily submit your app to the App Store, without it being rejected my friend.
Hope that helps. Keep coding.

Comment: Why do they test my app on an iPad when it is an iPhone-only app? It is not an universal app

Comment: They don't. They just run it on any device in the simulator. Who told you they test it on an iPad?

Comment: The resolution center! this is what they said: We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad running iOS 8.3, which is a violation of the App Store Review Guidelines.

Comment: hm. Could you please post a picture in your question?

Comment: Okay. I see. well.... to be honest just check your constraints and check yourself on the iPad. Change the constraints if necessary so that it runs on the iPad with an acceptable resolution and resubmit. It doesn't have to be beautiful, just run properly so that it get's accepted.

Comment: Ok I found the problem. My app is "Landscape Right" Only. But when I launch it in iPad retina mode, it begins with portrait, and than it turns to landscape. But the frame.size.width and frame.size.height are assigned to the portrait mode. Is it a bug in the new xcode?? I have no idea what is going on and what I have to do to avoid this. I can think of a method to make a own frame, but this shouldn't be necessary..?

Comment: No, it indeed shouldn't. Well. To be honest I have no idea. Start a new question, maybe someone can help you there.

Answer (score -3):

Nothing is wrong here , you can do this in debug mode for development purpose. Even you can run it on your iPad device from xCode. Don't worry about it, nothing wrong here.

Comment: Yes there is, because in my other app I can not choose the iPad simulator on iPhone-only apps. and my app is rejected because it doesn't run on the iPad as it should, but it is an iPhone only app so there is something wrong..