# Downloading "iPhone Only" apps on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

We are developing an app.

In the project settings and deployment section, the target device is selected as iPhone, which means that the app is iPhone only.

I have read that we can download iPhone only apps to iPads also, when we filter "iPhone only" on the AppStore. However, I couldn't able to do that. Users can install the app from their iPhones, but they can do that on their iPads when they select "iPhone only" in AppStore.

I think that, I have disabled that feature in settings but I couldn't find anything about that.

I hope that I could express the problem.
Thanks.

Comment: how long is your app in status "ready for sale"/online on the app store?

Comment: The first version of our app is "ready for sale" since Oct, 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to find an iPhone only app with the iPad.

1. Open the app store with your ipad
2. Search for your app
3. you will not find your app
4. select on the left upper corner from the filter "only iphone"
5. your app should appear

Regarding to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30596230/5327882), how does your `info.plist`, look like?

If there are any orientations with iPad, that could be the problem.

In one of my apps I have only the portrait mode in the supported orientations for iPhone like in the screenshot below (can find it without any problems via the iPad):

[image]

Comment: In the `info.plist` there is only "Supported Interface Orientation" with only "Portrait" option.

Comment: Moreover, last week our app is rejected by Apple because it was crashing on ipads. However, I can't even download it to ipad...

Comment: ok, strange. If there is no other solution on SO, contact the support team with a detailed explanation of your problem

Comment: After 1.5 years, I wanted to accept your answer, because I have added some new features in my info.plist which is not avaliable for ipads. I have figured that out at that time, and thanks for that :)