# Xcode, iOS app - How to disable iPad and Mac compatibility?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, testflight

I want to release my first iOS app on App Store. I would like to make it iOS only. Without an option to download and run on iPad and Mac.

However, TestFlight shows me this app on both iPad and Mac.

Why can I test my iOS app on iPad when I specifically disabled iPad in Target’s Deployment Info? How to disable it? How to prevent the app from distributing to iPad and Mac?

Deployment info is set to iPhone only. On App Store Connect I didn't add macOS app. And yet, it's still available in TestFlight and under compatibility it says: iPhone, iPad, macOS.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an option to prevent the app from being available to M1 macs in App Store Connect under *Pricing and availability*
[image]

Deselect the checkbox and the app won't appear in the Mac App Store.

Preventing your app from being installed on iPads is more difficult. Even if your app is not a Universal app with direct iPad support, iPads can download and run iPhone apps in a compatibility mode.

You may be able to limit your app availability by specifying `telephony` for [`UIDequiredDeviceCapabilities`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uirequireddevicecapabilities)

Comment: Thanks, I have this unchecked. I was confused, because I can see the app in TestFlight on both Mac and iPad. So this means that I can only test it with TestFlight on every device, but it won't be on Mac App Store? And on iPad people will see it as an iPhone app (no iPad Preview), but still will be able to download on iPad?

Comment: @mallow As per https://developer.apple.com/support/required-device-capabilities/#iphone-devices
it should not be visible for iPad. But previously we were able to install iPhone only apps on iPad which would just be running on iPad as if simulated. 
I also found this link if u care to refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40047689/downloading-iphone-only-apps-on-ipad

Comment: @mallow Also, please find the comments here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24974148

Comment: Thanks for further explanations, @singhabhi13

Answer (score 7):

For XCode 14.x this seems to be configured under **General** --> **Supported Destinations** - see **Configure the supported destinations for a target** section here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-a-multiplatform-app-target