# Apple Rejection App: We also noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad running iOS 10.2.1

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

My app is iPhone App only, and testing with iPad simulator work fine as in the screenshot. I don't understand this issue, and how to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Try this :http://stackoverflow.com/a/30596230/6602495

Comment: Check this answer and the comments.....http://stackoverflow.com/a/42603101/6602495