# Supporting only iPhone when submitting to Apple

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, app-store, app-store-connect

I submitted an update for my app in iTunes Connect which Apple rejected, giving the following reason:

> We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad running iOS 10.3. Specifically, the screen resolution was not optimized for iPad.

But I set the app to only support iPhone in the Deployment Info, under 'Devices', so I do not understand why they would test on an iPad.

I tried looking to find out how to make sure iPad isn't supported, but I do not have a storyboard for iPad and I only uploaded iPhone screenshots to the App store. How can I fix this error?

Comment: they tested in iPad because iPhone apps still runs in iPad with iPhone resolutions .. you also need to test in iPad with resolution is I think 320x480 .. more info http://stackoverflow.com/a/30595455/4601170

Comment: Could you mention the number of guideline that that caused the rejection? I assume is should be **2.xx** or something like that...

Comment: You need to test on iPhone 4 resolution

Comment: I received this exact rejection today.  (It's Guideline 2.4.1 - Performance)  Thank you @Paulw11 for the perfect suggestion I needed.